# Почему не работает атрибут download?

Tags: html

Учу `HTML`. Cделал таблицу с ссылками для скачивания логотипов браузеров. Использую `Chrome` для тестирования.

```html
<table border="0">
    <caption>Скачать логотипы</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Логотип</th>
        <th>Ссылка для скачивания</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/chrome.png"></img></td>
        <td><a href ="images/chrome.png" download>Скачать логотип</a></td>
    </tr>
    ...

    ...
</table>
```

---

Почему не работает атрибут `download` и картинка просто открывается в новой вкладке, а не загружается?

Comment: всё работает и загружается.

Comment: @Denis640Kb у меня нет.

Comment: значит проблема в настройках Вашего браузера. Атрибут работает корректно. https://jsfiddle.net/zmw5e3ok/

Comment: @Denis640Kb На абсолютный адрес и у меня сработало скачивание, а вот с файлами в images какая-то проблема.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Добавил к себе в href = "data:путь" все заработало. Магия

Comment: бывает и такое )))

Comment: @Denis640Kb а что это за атрибут атрибута такой data: ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указал в

```
<a href = "data:путь" download>Скачать логотип</a>
```

Все заработало.